# C++, array which elements point to strings

Tags: c++

When we declare  for example

```
const char* suit[3] = {"Head", "Dia", "Mod"};
```

this means that for example `suit[0]` stores the address of `"H"`. So why when you `std::cout << suit[0]` it prints `"Head"`?

Comment: Do note that `char * suit[3]={"Head","Dia","Mod"}` is not standard compliant

Answer (score 6):

Because when you call `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`, the library assumes the pointer points at the first element of a null-terminated array of characters - which it does here: `suit[0]` really points at the array `{'H', 'e', 'a', 'd', '\0'}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to only get 'H' you would have to write:

```
std::cout << suit[0][0] << std::endl;
```

because if you only say `suit[0]` you get a pointer to "Head", and the programm will print everything until it hits the `'\0'` character.
Simple pointer arithemtic.

Some examples:

```
std::cout << suit[1] << std::endl; //prints Dia
std::cout << suit[1][0] << std::endl; //prints D
std::cout << suit[2] << std::endl; //prints Mode
```